# C++ Equivalent of Java Generics

Tags: java, c++, code-translation

I need to convert some java classes into C++. For example, for a java interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ListenerManager<L> {

    void addListener(L listener);

    void removeListener(L listener);

}
```

My C++ is a bit rusty so I'm trying to figure out what the best way to translate this is. I was thinking something like this:

```
class IListener;
class ListenerManager
{
    virtual void add_listener(IListener listener);
    virtual void remove_listener(IListener listener);
};
```

and then define `IListener` as a base class somewhere else in the project.

Is this the right way to go?

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments! If I were to use templates, like this:

```
template<class L>
class ListenerManager
{
    virtual void add_listener(L listener);
    virtual void remove_listener(L listener);
};
```

... but I had a number of different listener types, say, `ListenerA` and `ListenerB`, do I then need to make a specialization for each type in the implementation?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%20(C++) Templates - like generics but less broken.

Comment: Just because you're writing C++ doesn't automatically mean you have to use underscores everywhere! CamelCase is fine too

Comment: I prefer underscores :)

Answer (score 4):

You mean *templates*?

Like e.g.

```
template<typename L>
class ListenerManager
{
    virtual void add_listener(L listener);
    virtual void remove_listener(L listener);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

While they are not exactly the same, Java Generics can be translated as C++ Templates.

```
template <typename T>
class ListenerManager
{
    virtual void add_listener(T listener);
    virtual void remove_listener(T listener);
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate in one line "not exactly the same" so to avoid main cross-language pitfalls ?

Answer (score 0):

You are after *templates* in C++; often compared, but not the same.

```
template <class L>
class ListenerManager
{
public:
  void add_listener(L listener);
  void remove_listener(L listener);
};
```

This will create a class typed on `L` that is your listener manager. The following code with create a class, where each `add_listener` method is a template and a different type can be used.

```
class ListenerManager
{
  template <class L>
  void add_listener(L listener);
  // ...
};
```

Based on the question and the examples; I suspect you are probably looking for a base class `IListener` of some sort to polymorphically handle the listeners in a container of some sort (in that way templates may not be the answer to the problem you have).